# How to get the key value in jquery autocomplete when data coming from web service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services, jquery-autocomplete

my auto complete is working fine as i can select the text . but problem is that i want to get the key value (Id) of selected item . so i can set on hidden field and use server side.

here is my web method code :

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<string> AuotExtenderHotel(string hotelname)
    {
        DataSet ds = objHotelList.GetHotels(hotelname);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            result.Add(dr["HotelName"].ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and here is my jquery autocomplete code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { HotelText(); });
    function HotelText() {
        $(".txthotel").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "WebService.asmx/AuotExtenderHotel",
                    data: "{'hotelname':'" + $('.txthotel').val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {

                        response(data.d);


                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }


                });
            }
        });
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? One of the [jQuery autocomplete events](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) is "select" and gets fired when the item is selected.

Comment: @moranjk yes i find that event but i am not getting idea how to get the value part of selected string

Comment: Look at the result of search.php used in the Demo of Autocomlete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=Great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you expect Id of the item in view if your server is not returning anything other than array of strings? I would modify the web method to return a JSON object which includes objects of ID and value pair. like

`[{ "id": "1", "label": "MyFirstHotel", "value": "MyFirstHotel" },{ "id": "2", "label": "MySecondHotel", "value": "MySecondHotel" }]`

Answer (score 0):

I really hope this was already figured out by now, but just in case...

The documentation states the "select" event gets fired when an item is selected and gives the prototype as being `select: function(event, ui) { ... }`

Placing a little `console.log(ui)` in the function shows the ui Object as:

```
{
  item :
  {
    label : "the selected label",
    value : "the selected value"
  }
}
```